# Is there a two-way key-stretching function which is infinite?

Tags: key-schedule

Only for hobby I made some ciphers, it is not my intention to use them in the real world but I am trying to compare them with existing ciphers.
An important function of my ciphers is a key stretching function with the following properties:
**Kn = increase(Kn-1) where Kn is totaly different from Kn-1 and the length of Kn is 23 - 26 % longer then Kn-1.**
**The opposite is of course Kn-1 = decrease(Kn).

And the increase function is infinite.**
I have been looking for an existing function with these properties for some time but have not found anything yet, i also cannot imagine that something like this is not already in use somewhere.

Is there a function with these or similar properties?

Comment: What's "diverent"?

Comment: Sorry translation error I've already corrected it.

Comment: Great, because diverent is halfway between different and divergent, which both have rather distinct meaning.